# Why having both default destructor and vector member prevents class to be "nothrow movable constructible"?

Tags: c++, c++17, destructor, move-semantics, type-traits

Given the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class Test {
public:
    ~Test() = default;
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
};


int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Test> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs `0`, meaning the `Test` class can't be "nothrow moved". However, if I remove either `~Test()` or `m_vector` then it returns `1`.

How to explain this please?

For reference, I'm using clang++-7 with C++17.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [[class.copy.ctor]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#8):

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if [other conditions omitted, and] `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

Thus, the `Test` class only has a copy constructor, not a move constructor. Any code that uses a `Test` rvalue to initialize a new `Test` object will use the copy constructor, which is not `noexcept` because of the vector member. If the vector member is removed, the copy constructor of `Test` will become trivial.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a user declared destructor, the class will not have an implicitly generated move constructor. Hence, moving will invoke copy constructor. The copy constructor of `std::vector` is potentially throwing, hence the implicit copy constructor of `Test` will also be potentially throwing.

Comment: Hmm. I added an explicit move constructor but it didn't help: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cb513630730164b)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat You need make it (and the destructor) `public`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Damn! (I feel stupid now.) ;-)